# Object Reference Error with BeginRenderLink in Sitecore MVC

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

The following code is throwing an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error and I can't figure out why. When I debug, my Model has the data I'm expecting. It seems very simple, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```cs
@using(BeginRenderLink(Model, x => x.Page, isEditable: true))
{
    @RenderImage(Model, x => x.IconImage, isEditable: true);
    @Editable(Model, x => x.Headline);
}
```

UPDATE: If I take the following two lines out of the BeginRenderLink block, they work as expected. Hopefully that makes sense to one of you...

```cs
@RenderImage(Model, x => x.IconImage, isEditable: true);
@Editable(Model, x => x.Headline);
```

Stack Trace

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView`1.BeginRenderLink(T model, Expression`1 field, NameValueCollection attributes, Boolean isEditable) +36
   ASP._Page_Views_Websites_Pool_Components_IconLink_IconLink_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\PentairPoolTest\Website\Views\Websites\Pool\Components\IconLink\IconLink.cshtml:5
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +146
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +106
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +374
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +89
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +833
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +833
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +710
```

Data model for relevant fields:

```cs
/// <summary>
        /// The Page field.
        /// <para></para>
        /// <para>Field Type: General Link</para>       
        /// <para>Field ID: 50770754-ec0c-4ac3-a05c-44aa8a278f69</para>
        /// <para>Custom Data: </para>
        /// </summary>
        [GeneratedCodeAttribute("Team Development for Sitecore - GlassItem.tt", "1.1")]
        [SitecoreField("Page")] 
        public virtual Link Page {get; set;}

    /// <summary>
            /// The IconImage field.
            /// <para></para>
            /// <para>Field Type: Image</para>      
            /// <para>Field ID: c5b9417e-2b29-461d-9e95-396fac25b3bb</para>
            /// <para>Custom Data: </para>
            /// </summary>
            [GeneratedCodeAttribute("Team Development for Sitecore - GlassItem.tt", "1.1")]
            [SitecoreField("IconImage")] 
            public virtual Image IconImage {get; set;} 
            /// <summary>
            /// The Headline field.
            /// <para></para>
            /// <para>Field Type: Single-Line Text</para>       
            /// <para>Field ID: 16f2ca59-68b4-412d-a021-7fdceaa50cb1</para>
            /// <para>Custom Data: </para>
            /// </summary>
            [GeneratedCodeAttribute("Team Development for Sitecore - GlassItem.tt", "1.1")]
            [SitecoreField("Headline")] 
            public virtual string Headline {get; set;}
```

Comment: Is there no other information in your stack trace? Can you also post your model and details of the fields they map to in Sitecore.

Comment: I've updated the question with some more details.

Comment: Can you copy program database file "Glass.Mapper.Sc.pdb" to you bin folder? It will give you much more information about error. You will see error line and will be able to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Is Model null? Not that this should matter but it might help diagnose

Comment: No, Model has the data I'd expect. In fact, if I take these two lines outside of the BeginRenderlink, they work.

@RenderImage(Model, x => x.IconImage, isEditable: true);
@Editable(Model, x => x.Headline);

Comment: What is the value of `Model.Page` - that is the object that is being complained about. Is that `null` ?

Comment: The value for Model.Page is as follows: Model.Page {Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Link}. If I do a regular RenderLink with the same Model, it renders correctly.